# Writing a script that calculates bending moment of cantilever beam in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an array

```
ssmat= [   10   9   7   6   3   2   1   0;
            0  20   5   0   0  15  10   0;
            0  10   0   0  15   0   0   0;
           10   0  10  10  10   0   0   0]
```

ssmatl=logical(ssmat)

```
ssmatl=[    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0;
            0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0;
            0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0;
            1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0]
```

First row of ssmat tells the distance from origin. And the fourth row, which is currently being worked with, tells the size of evenly distibuted load.

For example: Looking from left to right, since ssmat(4,1)~=0 it means that ssmat(1,1) is the point where the load starts and the closest nonzero value in fourth row is where it ends(ssmat(4,3)), the actual value is the magnitude of the load (10). In this case there are two evenly distributed loads from ssmat(4,1) to ssmat(4,3) and from ssmat(4,4) to ssmat(4,5).

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpEBR.png)

I am trying calculate the bending moment induced by these forces in different parts of the beam.  In this case thera are 14 points( Pp=14), Pp=2*(length(ssmat)-2).

The points are positioned like this:

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVfsK.png)

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ1mb.png)

The bending moment in point P is calculated like this:

[see calculation scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjLlD.png)

M=magnitude of the force* l*(l/2+d)

In the point P where there are multiple loads:

[see calculation scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Girf5.png)

M=magnitude of the force1* l1*(l1/2+d1)+magnitude of the force2* l2*(l2/2+d2).

If the point P was in betwen the beggining and the end of the load:

[see calculation scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsAse.png)

M=magnitude of the force1* l1*(l1/2)+magnitude of the force2* l2*(l2/2+d2).

I managed to write a script that works till the fifth point after that it gets trickier and currently just falls apart. Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

I hope I managed to explain the situation clearly. Feel free to ask any questions.

[Link to MatLab answers for post with images](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/519681-help-with-a-script-that-calculates-bending-moment-of-cantilever-beam?s_tid=prof_contriblnk)

```
if Pp==14
for i=1
        if sum(ssmatl(4,1:2))==0
            mg1=0;
            mg2=0;
            mg3=0;
        elseif sum(ssmatl(4,1:2))==1 && ssmat(4,i)==0
            mg1=0;
            mg2=0;
            mg3=mg2;
        elseif sum(ssmatl(4,1:2))==1 && ssmat(4,i)~=0
            mg1=0;
            mg2=ssmat(4,1)*abs(ssmat(1,2)-ssmat(1,1))*abs((ssmat(1,2)-ssmat(1,1))/2);
            mg3=mg2;
        elseif sum(ssmatl(4,1:2))==2
            mg1=0;
            mg2=ssmat(4,1)*abs(ssmat(1,2)-ssmat(1,1))*abs((ssmat(1,2)-ssmat(1,1))/2);
            mg3=mg2;
        end
end
for i=3:-1:1
    for j=2:-1:1
        if sum(ssmatl(4,1:3))==0
            mg4=0;
            mg5=0;
        elseif sum(ssmatl(4,1:3))==1 && ssmat(4,i)~=0
            mg4=ssmat(4,i)*abs(ssmat(1,3)-ssmat(1,i))*abs((ssmat(1,3)-ssmat(1,i))/2);
            mg5=mg4;
        elseif sum(ssmatl(4,1:3))==2 && ssmat(4,i)==ssmat(4,j) && i~=j
            mg4=ssmat(4,i)*abs(ssmat(1,i)-ssmat(1,j))*abs(((ssmat(1,i)-ssmat(1,j))/2)+(ssmat(1,3)-ssmat(1,i)))
            mg5=mg4;
        elseif sum(ssmatl(4,1:3))==3
            mg4=ssmat(4,1)*abs(ssmat(1,2)-ssmat(1,1))*abs(((ssmat(1,2)-ssmat(1,1))/2)+(ssmat(1,3)-ssmat(1,2)));
            mg5=mg4;
        end
    end
end
for i=4:-1:1
    for j=3:-1:1
        for k=2:-1:1
            if sum(ssmatl(4,1:4))==0
                mg6=0;
                mg7=mg6;
            elseif sum(ssmatl(4,1:4))==1 && ssmat(4,i)~=0
                mg6=ssmat(4,i)*abs(ssmat(1,4)-ssmat(1,i))*abs((ssmat(1,4)-ssmat(1,i))/2);
                mg7=mg6;
            elseif sum(ssmatl(4,1:4))==2 && ssmat(4,i)==ssmat(4,j) && i~=j
                mg6=ssmat(4,i)*abs(ssmat(1,i)-ssmat(1,j))*abs(((ssmat(1,i)-ssmat(1,j))/2)+(ssmat(1,4)-ssmat(1,i)));
                mg7=mg6;
            elseif sum(ssmatl(4,1:4))==3 && ssmat(4,4)==0
                mg6=(ssmat(4,1)*abs(ssmat(1,2)-ssmat(1,1))*abs(((ssmat(1,2)-ssmat(1,1))/2)+(ssmat(1,4)-ssmat(1,2))))+(ssmat(4,3)*abs(ssmat(1,4)-ssmat(1,3))*abs(((ssmat(1,4)-ssmat(1,3))/2)));
                mg7=mg6;
            elseif sum(ssmatl(4,1:4))==3 && ssmat(4,j)==ssmat(4,k) && j~=k
                mg6=ssmat(4,j)*abs(ssmat(1,j)-ssmat(1,k))*abs(((ssmat(1,j)-ssmat(1,k))/2)+(ssmat(1,4)-ssmat(1,j)));
                mg7=mg6;
            end
        end
    end
end
for i=5:-1:1
    for j=4:-1:1
        for k=1:4
            for l=2:-1:1
                if sum(ssmatl(4,1:5))==0
                    mg8=0;
                    mg9=mg8;
                elseif sum(ssmatl(4,1:5))==1 && ssmat(4,i)~=0
                    mg8=ssmat(4,i)*abs(ssmat(1,5)-ssmat(1,i))*abs((ssmat(1,5)-ssmat(1,i))/2);
                    mg9=mg8;
                elseif sum(ssmatl(4,1:5))==2 && ssmat(4,i)==ssmat(4,j) && i~=j
                    mg8=ssmat(4,i)*abs(ssmat(1,i)-ssmat(1,j))*abs(((ssmat(1,i)-ssmat(1,j))/2)+(ssmat(1,4)-ssmat(1,i)));
                    mg9=mg8;
                elseif sum(ssmatl(4,1:5))==3 && ssmat(4,
                    mg8=(ssmat(4,1)*abs(ssmat(1,2)-ssmat(1,1))*abs(((ssmat(1,2)-ssmat(1,1))/2)+(ssmat(1,4)-ssmat(1,2))))+(ssmat(4,3)*abs(ssmat(1,4)-ssmat(1,3))*abs(((ssmat(1,4)-ssmat(1,3))/2)));
                    mg9=mg8;
                elseif sum(ssmatl(4,1:4))==3 && ssmat(4,j)==ssmat(4,k) && j~=k
                    mg8=ssmat(4,j)*abs(ssmat(1,j)-ssmat(1,k))*abs(((ssmat(1,j)-ssmat(1,k))/2)+(ssmat(1,4)-ssmat(1,j)));
                    mg9=mg8;
```

Comment: This seems like an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. You're running into trouble because of the approach you are taking to solve the problem. Typically, these type of problems are solved by having an array corresponding to each *and every* sectional property. For eg., your load distribution (assuming piecewise constant) would be specified as `load = [10 10 10 0 10 10 10 0 0 0]`. Similarly, all sectional parameters in your equations would be arrays having values corresponding to each section. An element-wise multiplication is then sufficient.